# Отправка веб-формы на адрес указанный в форме Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, формы, phpword

Есть веб-формы на сайте, так же на странице просмотра заполненной формы я подключил phpWord и теперь можно скачать сгенерированный вордовский файл из заполненной формы. Так вот, можно ли как ни будь сделать так что бы при заполнении формы, когда человек нажимает на кнопку отправить, генерировался вордовский файл и отправлялся на почту которую пользователь указал в веб-форме?

Comment: а почему не  excel или xml ?  зачем World ?

Comment: Такова задача. Нужен именно Ворд, из веб формы генерируется документ, нечто вроде договора. Для админа есть возможность сгенерировать из документ из данных формы, а вот хотелось бы что бы ещё при заполнении формы генерировался документ и отправлялся пользователю

Comment: По идее вообще не важно какой будет документ, главное найти способ отправить файл на почту указанную в форме

Comment: а не проще просто тогда поля формы в теле письма отправить? Это реализуется чистыми средствами битрикса

Comment: Так я про это и спрашиваю, можно ли отправить вообще что либо на мыло указанное пользователем в форме!?